# Increase OpenGL display size

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm just starting to learn OpenGL in Qt, and I've been following a demo clip from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nzHSkY4K18), but my display is not same as the display in clip. It looks very small. Is there any way to make it bigger?

I tried to change to the coordinates of the triangle drawing code like:

```
glColor3f(1,1,0);
glScalef(1, 1, 0.0);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glVertex3f(-10,-10,0);
glVertex3f(10,-10,0);
glVertex3f(0.0,10,0);
glEnd();
```

But, it didn't draw a triangle. My output became a square. See these screen shots for [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7awle.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9NDF.png) my changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the viewport appropriately (namely the window client region dimensions). At the start of `paintGL` call `glViewport(0, 0, width(), height());`.

Also later on you probably want to set appropriate *projection* and *modelview* transformations.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is the answer of my problem. :)